# ESP8266 WiFiClient connection always returns 0

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to use a NodeMCU as a station to connect to a webserver, however, the WiFiClient connect function always returns 0 for no reason. I am able to connect the NodeMCU to my home WiFi, but it just cannot connect to any server (either with IP address or with URL).

If anyone is interested, the following is the testing code (I did not include the libraries intentionally for the clearness of the code).

```
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
IPAddress server(74,125,115,105);  // Google

// Initialize the client library
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP specified during programming");
  WiFi.begin("mySSID", "myPassword");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {delay(500); Serial.print("."); }
  Serial.print("\r\nWiFi connected IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(client.connect(server,80));
}
```

Comment: I rolled back the question to original version answered by Jaromanda

Comment: i tried reaching the IP address in you code, using a web browser, without success ..... no response to ping either ............ please use a valid IP address in your code ...... update your post with corrected info

Comment: @JaromandaX, please undelete your answer